# Shader Nodes - Texture Coordinate Node - How to move the "center" of the "Window" output

Tags: shader-nodes, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping, npr

I've used this output before in order to give objects flat/2D-looking "Chowder-like" materials, I've mostly been using it because it doesn't get distorted by the shape of the object, it stays nice and flat.
[image: Example node setup]

This time instead of a material I'd like to apply a gradient [set the color ramp to constant so it's easier to see what I wanna do] and I'd like for it to "follow" the object.

For example: If the object moves to the right side of the screen, I want the texture to move in the same direction by the same amount.

I'm aware that I can manually adjust the values in the mapping node's "location" socket [I did just that for the images below], it would be way more convenient for me however if I could make it automatic, so the "center" of the "window" is wherever the object is without me having to manually adjust it each time.

In short, here's what happens when I move the cube from the image above to the right:
[image: What Happens]

And here's what I want to happen:
[image: What I want to happen, rough recreation]

**In case there's a completely different method for this or a workaround:**

What I want to do is essentially apply a "2D Gradient" on an object, one that looks like what you'd get if you put a render of the object in an image-editing software [example: Photoshop] and applied a gradient on top of/over it.

Comment: If it's only a gradient you should use object coordinates. Is it only a gradient or is it going to be a 2D texture?

Comment: also what do you mean by 2d gradient? A gradient is 1D, unless there are two gradients on top of each other.

Comment: I might have gotten the terms mixed up, my apologies. By "2D gradient" I meant one that look 2D, as in it looks like it has been applied in a [2D] image editing software.
Basically I want it to look flat, I don't want it to follow the object's shape/geometry in any way.

I'm very sorry if it doesn't make much sense, I've recently started doing 3D after only doing 2D.

Comment: I am just trying to understand, that's all.